# Как запустить php скрипт в браузере?

Tags: php, apache2

скрипт лежит в корне сайта.
Запускаю в браузере. Выдает только код самого скрипта как текст, при этом не выполняется.

В консоли, судя по всему, выполняется, но просто выдает мне html страницу текстом (в общем-то результатом скрипта должна открыться эта страница в браузере). Но опять же ссылки там неправильно формируются.

Вообще это скрипт bigdump.php
https://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/
Думаю, может настроить нужно сам apache, для отображения скриптов, но что-то тоже не получается. Подскажите решение.

php5.3.29
Apache/2.4.7

Comment: php это серверный язык и в браузере он не запускается

Comment: `catalog.site/bigdump.php` так он не запуститься? а как тогда запустить?

Comment: Нужно настроить сам apache. Только вот не стесняйтесь и расскажите, что именно у вас не получается-то, иначе придётся вас отправить в гугл за инструкциями по настройке :)

Comment: мне нужно запустить скрипт, пытаюсь запустить его пройдя в браузере `catalog.site/bigdump.php`, где `bigdump.php` нужный скрипт, лежит в корне. Результатом скрипта будет формирование html страницы с нужными ссылками. Но открывается в браузере у меня лишь сам скрипт(текст)

Comment: Через консоль: прямо в консоль текcтом формируется html, при этом ссылки получаются неправильные

Comment: Apache не в курсе, что *.php - это скрипт. Нужно установить модуль apache-php (смотрите как у вас в ОС он называется), обычно вместе с модулем в Apache попадает файл конфигурации, и там - AddHandler на *.php файлы, которые не просто отдаются, а выполняются

Comment: Вам легче установить OpenServer...

Comment: Если при вызове php скрипта apache отдает его как html, значит у вас не настроен mod_php (apache php module). Проверьте содержимое httpd.conf или apache2.conf (в зависимости от системы). Кстати, какая у вас система?